# How do I enable developer mode on Ubuntu phones?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, adb

How do I get access to Ubuntu phone devices over adb from a host PC, or via the phablet-shell tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done from System Settings.

Open System Settings, About this Phone, Developer Mode.

The adb service will be enabled if 'developer mode' is selected. Note that you must have some sort of lock screen security enabled (pin or password), and 'Developer mode' will be greyed out if that's not the case.

The 'Lock Security' menu there can be used to turn on a pin or password.

Comment: Are there any developer settings available? Where?